# Como desaparezco por completo el Menú cuando está oculto, para que no ocupe espacio a la derecha

Tags: responsive, jmenubar

Tengo un Menú Hamburguesa Responsive. Y se abre y oculta cuando das click.

Cuando la pantalla es menos de 768px es cuando aparece el menu hamburguesa. Y se traslada a la derecha con la propiedad **transform:translateX(100%)** para que se traslade al lado derecho y así no se vea en mi pantalla, cuando doy click en el menú hamburguesa vuelve, pero cuando se guarda me ocupa un espacio que no quiero. El Problema está ahí.

Cuando está guardado el menú me ocupa un espacio de lado derecho y está aumentando mi ancho y desmaqueta toda la página

Le doy en inspección de código y es que al ponerlo todo a la derecha el ancho aumenta, habría una posibilidad de arreglar esto ?

Alguien tiene alguna luz de como arreglar este problema?

Tengo el codepen aqui : https://codepen.io/Marvinfx/pen/XWroWxW

```js
const navSlide = () => {
     const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
     const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
     const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

    
  burger.addEventListener('click' ,()=> 
      // Toggle Nav */
     {nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

     //Animate Links */
     navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
               if (link.style.animation) {
                   link.style.animation="";
               } else {
                    link.style.animation = `navLinksFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
               }
          
     });
       //Burger Animation
       burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
     


}

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
     margin:0px;
     padding: 0px;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -o-transition-box-sizing:border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
     display:flex;
     justify-content:space-around;
     align-items:center;
     min-height:8vh;
     background-color:#5d4954;
     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
     color:rgb(226,226,226);
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 5px;
     font-size:20px;
}

.nav-links {
     display:flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     width:30%;
}

.nav-links li {
     list-style:none;
}

.nav-links a {
     color:rgb(226,226,226);
     text-decoration: none;
     letter-spacing: 3px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size:14px;
}
.burger {
     display:none;
     cursor:pointer;
}
.burger div {
     width:25px;
     height:3px;
     background-color:rgb(226,226,226);
     margin:5px;
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
     .nav-links {
          width:68%;
     }

}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
     
     body {
          overflow-x:hidden;
     }

     .nav-links {
     position: absolute;
     right:0px;
     height:92vh;
     top:8vh;
     background-color:#5d4954;
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column;
     align-items:center;
     width:50%;
     transform:translateX(100%);
     transition: transform .5s ease-in;
     }
      
     .nav-links li {
          opacity:0;
     }
     .burger {
          display:block;
     }
}

.nav-active {
     transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinksFade {
     from {
          opacity:0;
          transform: translateX(50px);
     }
     to {
          opacity:1;
          transform:translateX(0px);
     }
}

.toggle .line1 {
     transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}
.toggle .line2 {
     opacity:0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
     transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Navigation</title>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    
    
<body>
     <nav>
            <div class="logo">
               <h4>The Nav</h4>
            </div>
             <ul class="nav-links">
               <li><a href="#">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">About</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Works</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
           <div class="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
           </div>
     </nav>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A que tamaño te refieres exactamente ? al margen del icono de "menu" estando cerrado??

Comment: Si, disculpame la demora. Cuando esta cerrado ocupa un espacio, aumentando asi el ancho.